# Evaluate $\iiint_V(xyz)dxdydz$, $\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}\leq z \leq \sqrt{1-x^2 -y^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Evaluate $\iiint_V(xyz)dxdydz$, $\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}\leq z \leq \sqrt{1-x^2 -y^2}$.

---

$\theta$ will be in interval $[0, 2\pi]$. Substituting ${x^2 +y^2}$ with $r^2$ we will have $|r|\leq z\leq \sqrt{1-r^2}$ and thus $0\leq z\leq \sqrt{1-r^2}$. Rising LHS and middle of first equality we get $x^2 +y^2 \leq z^2$, so $r^2\leq z^2$. Thus, $r\in[0, z]$. Am I correct? If not, what's the correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why did you go from $\lvert r\rvert\leq z\leq\sqrt{1-r^2}$ to $0\leq z\leq\sqrt{1-r^2}$?

We have $r\leq\sqrt{1-r^2}$ if and only if $r\leq 1/\sqrt2$.  So
$$
\iiint_V xyz\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z = \int_0^{1/\sqrt2} \int_r^{\sqrt{1-r^2}} \int_0^{2\pi} r^2z\cos\theta\sin\theta\, r\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}z\,\mathrm{d}r
$$